# Zend Framework :: How should title html element get from view?(set view->headTitle())

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

Zend Framework :: How should  title html element get from view?(set view->headTitle()).

Example of view title output source: (I need to get: some browser title)

```
<title> some browser title </title>
```

My Code that print huge array:

```
$this->view->headTitle('some browser title');//set working
echo var_export($this->headTitle()); //get not working
```

please help to get title element of the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In view

```
$this->headTitle('some browser title');
echo $this->headTitle(); //<title>some browser title<title>
echo strip_tags($this->headTitle()); //some browser title
```

Answer (score 1):

Think it should be:

`$this->view->headTitle('some browser title')`;

to set the page title.

Comment: this is not the reason, in real code it was also $this->view->headTitle

Answer (score 0):

Change your set to:

```
$this->view->headTitle('some browser title');
```

and your get to:

```
echo var_export($this->headTitle);
```

(notice the removal of the "()" after headTitle).

Comment: this is not the reason, in real code it was also $this->view->headTitle

Comment: Please also see my suggested change to the get (just edited my post to add it).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution by far to get the returned value of view helper:

```
$titleTag = (string)$this->headTitle(); //with title tag, use strip tags to get the title ;)
```